# Is this possible to print a Pages document on Windows?

Tags: windows, pages

I know it's a bit weird, but I received a Pages document. I'm currently on a Windows machine. Can I have some kind of preview/quicklook of the document or print it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

1. Save the file locally on your windows computer.
2. Right click on the file and select rename.
3. Remove .pages extension and enter .zip as the extension and press enter.
4. Open the zip file and it should allow you open the file and its contents.

Comment: Jaw-dropping solution :-O Excellent!!